# How to change the reference to the Oracle to SAS folder

Tags: sas

I have a reference to a folder that is on Oracle, but the libraries have already been transferred to the SAS server. I do not know how to add / change to open the file outside Oracle

````
            datafile="&glb_path.\01_projects\credit\_test\RCDT2021.xlsx"
            dbms=excel replace;
     sheet="RCDTCOD"; 
     getnames=yes;
     mixed=yes;
     usedate=yes;
     scantime=yes;```


This folder is 1: 1 already on shared disc. ```\01_projects\credit\_test\RCDT2021.xlsx"```
````

Comment: Why do have what appears to be part of a PROC IMPORT step to read from an XLSX file when your question is about ORACLE?  What does the XLSX file have to do with ORACLE (or SAS for that matter).

Comment: Maybe I worded the question wrong. I want to open a file with shared drive not from oracle

Comment: @Tom i would change to  corp.ad.gs.com 'ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /home/V1410190/corp.ad.gs.com'

Comment: You seem to be using "Oracle" to mean something other than the relational database product that Oracle sells. Is Oracle the name of some server or disk on your system instead of a database?

Comment: You cannot use Windows style paths when running on Unix.  Use a Unix style path.  Ask the system administrator for your SAS server where the files you want to reference are mounted in the Unix filesystem.

Comment: This isn't a SO type question, this is ask your SAS administrator or a colleague type question because it relies a lot on your specific set up and paths. In general, it seems like you're running a SAS server, which means that it may not see your desktop. Talk to your IT team.